# Is there any way to autoincrement a sql server id by doubling?

Tags: sql-server, double, auto-increment

Can I set up an auto-increment on an id field in sql server that will double the id with each row?

Comment: You mean that each row has double value of the previous, like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...?

Comment: What would be the point? There would be a seriously low limit on the total number of rows - such that just pre-populating them seems to be feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only increment arithmetically (by adding) and not geometrically (by multiplying).
Such a feature would not be useful anyway. If the first row has the value of 1, and you multiply by 2, the row values would be 1, 2, 4, 8,... 18446744073709551616 for the 64-th row.

That last value is too big to fit in a `bigint` column, so you could only store up to 63 rows per table.

If you do need less than 64 rows, then it's not too much of a hassle to turn off the autoincrement on the primary key, and just use set values.

Comment: oh well. thanks. we were thinking of using this for some binary processing, but we will probably end up storing the field as a hex string because of the size limitation

Comment: SQL Server has `binary` and `varbinary` column types for storing binary data, you could (and should) use them to hold data for binary processing.

Comment: Use an increment of 1 and then do the math on it yourself.  That is, 0 = power(2, 0), 1 = power(2, 1), etc.  But as SWeko points out, you're still limited to using 63 "bits"

Comment: The limit is actually 62 rows because BigInt is signed.  To add to @Ben-Thul 's comment. I've seen this done with 2 columns. First col is the Identity with an increment of one. Insert all your rows, then after that do a separate update to the 2nd column in the table to equal Power(cast( 2 as BigInt),IdentityColumn). You need to make sure it is a BigInt. After that, create a clustered index on the second column. You can't make it primary key because it will have more than 1 NULL row initially. This feature is rarely useful, but the specific case I've seen is justified (doing some bitwise ops)

Comment: Here's a quick proof that it's 62. Try both of these:

select  power(cast(2 as bigint),63)

Select power(cast(2 as bigint),62)